# The upper semi-continuous rank of a module sheaf 

Tags: modules, sheaf-theory

The article "Intuitionistic algebra and representations of rings" is fantastic; it develops the language, logic etc. for the topos $Sh(X)$, where $X$ is a fixed topological space, from scratch and thereby illuminating most of the known (and more) notions of sheaf theory in the sense that they become more natural. Thanks again [Peter Arndt](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34228/does-every-nontrivial-sheaf-of-rings-have-a-maximal-ideal) for this reference.

On page 37, the rank of a module $M$ is introduced as a upper Dedekind cut in the sheaf $\mathbb{N}$, or equivalently as a upper semi-continuous function $r : X \to \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$. Now it is claimed that it is given explicitely by mapping $x$ to the minimal number of generators needed for the stalks $M_x$. However, I don't see why this should be upper semi-continuous. I can show that only in the case that $M$ is locally of finite type. In fact, when I track back the constructions I get, that $r(x)$ is the infimum of numbers of sections which generate $M|_U$, where $U$ varies over the open neighborhoods of $x$.

Is this the correct definition of the rank?

Basically the same question applies to the definition of the independence $i(x)$, which is claimed to be the maximal number of linearly independent elements in $M_x$. Again, I don't see why this should be lower semi-continuous.

Answer (score 4):

This ought to be a comment, but I don't have the necessary reputation. I believe the claim is indeed false unless $M$ is locally of finite type. Here's a bit of context:

1. It's always the case that an internal upper Dedekind cut $A$ in $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$ induces an upper semi-continuous function $X \to \mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty \}$, by mapping $x \in X$ to $\inf\{ n \in \mathbb{N} | \exists \text{open} V \subseteq X, x \in V: V \models (n \in A) \}$. This function takes values in $\mathbb{N}$ iff the cut is inhabited (in the internal sense).
2. The internally defined cut $A = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | \text{there exists a generating family for $M$ consisting of $n$ elements} \}$ is inhabited iff $M$ is in the internal sense a finitely generated module, i.e. in the usual external sense locally of finite type.
3. Let $r$ be the function induced by this cut. It's easy to prove that the stalk $M_x$ can be generated by $r(x)$ elements. The reverse implication, that if $M_x$ can be generated by $n$ elements then $r(x) \leq n$, can be proven if $M$ locally of finite type.

So $r(x)$ coincides with the minimal number of generators needed for the stalk $M_x$ if $M$ is locally of finite type (at least in an open neighbourhood of $x$). If $M$ is not locally of finite type, $r$ will still be upper semi-continuous, but might not coincide with the minimal number of generators.

I don't know the "correct" definition of the rank if the module is not locally of finite type.