# Is a locally free sheaf projective in the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules when $X$ is an affine scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be an affine scheme and $\mathcal{E}$ a finitely generated locally free sheaf on $X$. It is obvious that $\mathcal{E}$ is a projective object in the category Qcoh$(X)$ since we can pass to rings and modules.

My question is: is $\mathcal{E}$ still projective when we consider it in the larger category  $\mathcal{O}_X$-mod which consists of all $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules? If it is true, how to prove it in a "cohomological way"?

I'm not sure whether this question is suitable for mathoverflow. Please feel free to move it if necessary.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This answer is inspired by the discussion [at this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5378/when-are-there-enough-projective-sheaves-on-a-space-x). Let $X$ be an integral affine scheme admitting an open cover $X=U\cup V$ with $U$, $V$ and $X$ all distinct. I claim that $\mathscr O_X$ is not projective in $\operatorname{Mod}(\mathscr O_X)$. Let $i\colon U\hookrightarrow X$ and $j\colon V\hookrightarrow X$ be the inclusion morphisms. There is an obvious surjection $p\colon i_! \mathscr O_U\oplus j_! \mathscr O_V\twoheadrightarrow \mathscr O_X$ (check surjectivity on stalks). If $\mathscr O_X$ were projective, $p$ would split, so we would have $\Gamma(\mathscr O_X)\hookrightarrow \Gamma(i_!\mathscr O_U)\oplus \Gamma(j_! \mathscr O_V)=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for obvious question. Why is $\Gamma(i_! \mathcal{O}_U) \oplus \Gamma(i_! \mathcal{O}_V) = 0$?

Comment: The lower shriek is this case is just extension by zero, so $\Gamma(W, i_! \mathcal{O}_U) = \Gamma(W,\mathcal{O}_U)$ if $W\subset U$, and $0$ otherwise. So in this case $\Gamma(i_! \mathcal{O}_U) = \Gamma(i_! \mathcal{O}_V) = 0$, since $U$ and $V$ are strict subsets of $X$.